# How to measure time and RAM usage for recursive function?

Tags: python, performance, time

I want to benchmark QuickSort, and BubbleSort. My task it's measure time, CPU usage, and memory usage for both.
I wrote code, and in BubbleSort everything works fine. But I have a problem with QuickSort.
Example script result:

```
> How many elements in list?5                                           
> bubble_sort function took 0.000 ms                                    
> quick_sort function took 0.000 ms                                     
> quick_sort function took 0.000 ms                                     
> quick_sort function took 0.000 ms                                     
> quick_sort function took 0.000 ms                                     
> quick_sort function took 0.000 ms                                     
> quick_sort function took 1.863 ms                                     
> quick_sort function took 3.360 ms                                     
> quick_sort function took 5.353 ms                                     
> quick_sort function took 6.896 ms                                     
> None                                                                  
> Filename: main.py                                                     
> Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents          
> ============================================================                                                                 5   26.281 MiB   26.273 MiB          10       def wrap(*args,
> **kwargs):                                                6   26.281 MiB    0.004 MiB          10           time1 = time.time()            
> 7   26.281 MiB    0.000 MiB          10           ret = f(*args,
> **kwargs)                                              8   26.281 MiB    0.000 MiB          10           time2 = time.time()                                                   9   26.281 MiB    0.004 MiB          10           print('{:s} function
> took {:.3f} ms'.format(f.__name__, (time2-time1)*1000.0))             
> 10                                                                    
> 11   26.281 MiB    0.000 MiB          10           return ret
```

As u can see bubble sort give me one line with time, and QS give me 2*list elements.
Next: RAM result (table below give me result for whole program (?) not for each function.

Resume: I want to one final time for each function, and memory_profiler info for each function separatly.
How can I do that?

My code looks that (it's long but i think for better explanation I need to show u whole):

```
import random, time

def timing(f):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        time1 = time.time()
        ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
        time2 = time.time()
        print('{:s} function took {:.3f} ms'.format(f.__name__, (time2-time1)*1000.0))

        return ret
    return wrap


def create_random_list(elements_n):
    l = [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(elements_n)]
    return l


@profile
@timing
def bubble_sort(gen_list):
    n = len(gen_list)

    for i in range(n - 1):

        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):

            if gen_list[j] > gen_list[j + 1]:
                gen_list[j], gen_list[j + 1] = gen_list[j + 1], gen_list[j]

    return gen_list

### QS
def partition(gen_list, start, end):
    pivot = gen_list[start]
    low = start + 1
    high = end

    while True:

        while low <= high and gen_list[high] >= pivot:
            high = high - 1

        while low <= high and gen_list[low] <= pivot:
            low = low + 1
        if low <= high:
            gen_list[low], gen_list[high] = gen_list[high], gen_list[low]
        else:
            break

    gen_list[start], gen_list[high] = gen_list[high], gen_list[start]

    return high


@profile
@timing
def quick_sort(array, start, end):
    if start >= end:
        return

    p = partition(array, start, end)
    quick_sort(array, start, p-1)
    quick_sort(array, p+1, end)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = int(input("How many elements in list?"))
    test_list = create_random_list(num)
    bubble_sort(test_list)
    print(quick_sort(test_list, 0, len(test_list) - 1))
```

Comment: Define and use a context manager instead, so that you only measure the "root" call, rather than "every" call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use context managers when you want control over which function call gets measured.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def timing(f):
    time1 = time.time()
    yield
    time2 = time.time()
    print('{} function took {:.3f} ms'.format(f, (time2-time1)*1000.0))

[...]

def quick_sort(array, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(array) - 1

    if start >= end:
        return

    p = partition(array, start, end)
    quick_sort(array, start, p-1)
    quick_sort(array, p+1, end)

num = int(input("How many elements in list?"))
test_list = create_random_list(num)

with timing("quicksort"):
    quicksort(test_list)
```

You can likely do something similar with `profile`.

Comment: Thank U, I implement context manager and It's work fine !  Thanks!